# Best way to indicate usage of 'points' to offset an amount?

Tags: usability, forms, buttons, user-expectation

I'm having a bit of a dilemma on how to properly do the interface for using points to offset an amount.

Let's say I have 5000 points in my wallet. Of course, I need to indicate that I have 5000 points (as you can see in the header below).

However, as I start to indicate the points I wanna use, should the header change accordingly? Because if I'm using 5000 points, I should have 0 points (in real time).

I added a 'points remaining' below which helps but I feel there's a lot of text about the points, which can be quite confusing.

What is a better way to handle / simplify this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you change the header when indicating points it will look like the operation is already done. (You had 5000points, but now you have 4000points.) The amount of points you have should only change when you finalizing the operation.

Also I think that 'points to use:' is also a bit confusing. You probably meant to indicate that this points are going to be used in transaction, but the sentence can be understand in the other way. 'Points to use' sound as an indicator of how much points you have available in your stock. I would refraze 'points to use' into 'exchange points for money'. I think it will tell more accurately what is happening. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have: **5000** points

Points to use: **5000**

Points left: **0**

I think it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As a user (but I am no typical user) I would like to see both sets of numbers:

The points-in-wallet and the original-amount, followed by the points-remaining and the discounted-amount.

The first two numbers are fixed and indicate the values that a ‘reset’ might return to. They indicate the starting point of the transaction.

The last two numbers indicate the result of the transaction and can be updated on changing the points to use, or the discount to achieve. They represent the choice made when completing the transaction.